# Scala and Annotation

Tags: scala, guice

Just thinking of implementing Guice in scala

Any sample code ?

Comment: Do you want to _implement_ Guice in Scala or _use_ Guice with Scala?

Comment: i want to use Guice with Scala. just a sample how to use both the concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you specifically need Guice to add Scala to an existing Java-based project that uses framework, I'd advocate that you just use built-in language features instead.

Traits and implicits can give you all the Dependency Injection you'll need.  You might also want to search online for the Cake pattern.

Comment: Exactly. While Guice is certainly a nice and clever solution for Java's problems with statics, singletons initialization etc, Scala just doesn't have these problems.

Comment: is there any equivalent to Guice's scopes when using the Cake pattern?

Comment: Wrapping everything in traits looks not so clean while DI frameworks require only to add annotations.

Comment: implicits aren't "wrapping everything in traits", and too many annotations just look like so many twitter IDs sprinkled like warts throughout your codebase.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di) post about DI in Scala will be able to help you to get going with Guice. See Using Google Guice topic.